# Assistance with while loops

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

In the below code I would like the counter to remain on 0 rather than go into negative figures when one of the stock hits 0 which continuing to count the other items down.

```
cheese = 1
sausage = 3
tomato = 3

while cheese > 0 or sausage > 0 or tomato > 0:
  print("Cheese stock:")
  print(cheese)
  print("Sausage stock:")
  print(sausage)
  print("Tomato stock:")
  print(tomato)
  cheese -=1
  sausage -=1
  tomato -=1
```

I totally understand why this runs to negative numbers - the "or" operator means that it will do so however if I use the "and" operator it will only run once, understandably so.

Answer (score 2):

Use conditional statement to achieve this:

```
cheese = 1
sausage = 3
tomato = 3

while cheese > 0 or sausage > 0 or tomato > 0:
  print("Cheese stock:")
  print(cheese)
  print("Sausage stock:")
  print(sausage)
  print("Tomato stock:")
  print(tomato)
  if cheese > 0:
      cheese -=1
  if sausage > 0:
      sausage -=1
  if tomato > 0:
      tomato -=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You should only decrement the counters, if their value is a positive integer (greater than zero).
Using `if` conditional statement, the following should give you the result:

```
cheese  = 1
sausage = 3
tomato  = 3

while cheese > 0 or sausage > 0 or tomato > 0:
  print("Cheese stock:  \n", cheese)
  print("Sausage stock: \n", sausage)
  print("Tomato stock:  \n", tomato)

  if cheese  > 0: cheese  -=1
  if sausage > 0: sausage -=1
  if tomato  > 0: tomato  -=1
```